# PHP link navigation inside link navigation

Tags: php, hyperlink, web

I created a simple webshop with PHP. The header, footer and navigation is fixed and when I click through the navigation only the main area changes and the link changes too (for exaple `index.php?page=shop`).

Now I want to use pagination for the articles. Every time I click on another page it will change the link too (for example `index.php?page=shop?id=5`). The `id` is the page number. But this doesn't work in PHP. It always links me to the start page.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: There can only be one single question mark in a URL, afterwards you need to use am ampersand: `index.php?page=shop&id=5`

Answer (score 0):

There are only one single question mark in URL in place of two when u pass more than two parameters in URL it should be

```
index.php?page=shop&id=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Like arkascha said , index.php?page=shop&id=5 then you get this parameter with $_GET['id'] , check if isset and load next pag.